# Nativescript - Tabview flashing transition

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm encountering a problem with the 'Tab Navigation' template of **Nativescript (V4) with Angular**, with Android, on emulator (*Nougat v7.1.1*) or on the device (*Oreo 8.1*).

When I navigate between tabs, the screen "flashes". The behavior seems linked to the use of several "page-router-outlet".

I tried the solution described [Nativescript Forum](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/smooth-page-transitions-on-android/114/15), without success.

With the `<item name=“android:windowAnimationStyle”>@null</item>` in AppThemeBase, I encounter an error of the type

```
System.err: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onViewAttachedToWindow failed
System.err:
System.err: TypeError: Cannot set property 'transitionType' of null
```

(both on emulator or device).

[a little video showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgu86.gif)

If someone has an idea ? :)

Comment: Since you have mentioned NativeScript Angular 4.x, I assume you must be using TNS 3.x. Were you able to reproduce the same on latest SDKs (Angular 6.x and TNS 4.x)?

Comment: Hi, I'm on TNS 4.2.4, with nativescript-angular and Angular packages in version 6.1.0 and I use the latest version of 'Tab Navigation' template with multipe page-router-outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found this issue to be linked to 2 key things in NativeScript core modules:

- For iOS we need a way to set nav bar hidden much earlier and without animation, ie:

`constructor(frame: Frame) {
  this._controller = UINavigationControllerImpl.initWithOwner(new WeakRef(frame));
   // This needs to be set early to avoid white flashes when changing page-router-outlets preferably in the constructor for iOS frame
  this._controller.setNavigationBarHiddenAnimated(true, false);
}`

We've also found it helps for iOS to set transparent background on the controllers when they are constructed, ie in `page.ios.ts` where this occurs:

`const controller = UIViewControllerImpl.initWithOwner(new WeakRef(this));
this.viewController = this._ios = controller;
// controller.view.backgroundColor = whiteColor; (This is what it's doing now which obviously could cause a white flash)
controller.view.backgroundColor = new Color("#00000000").ios; // instead could ensure transparent to start`

- on Android the fix resides in nativescript-angular PR here:
  https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/pull/1569

More discussion here:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/6454#issuecomment-433176056